# rsync command works in Bash but hangs when invoked from Perl

Tags: rsync, perl

I have an rsync command that works fine from either the Bash command line or a Bash script.

The command is: `rsync -qtz user@hostname:/tmp/p /tmp`

When I run the command, it copies the file and runs in less than a second.

If I put the command in a Perl script, the script hangs, and I have to Control-C to kill it.

The Perl script is just this:

```
system("rsync -qtz user@hostname:/tmp/p /tmp");
```

What could be going wrong?  Other commands (like mv and gzip) work fine in the Perl script.  I tried specifying the4 complete path to /usr/bin/rsync, but it doesn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `@` symbol is special inside double quoted strings in Perl.

It is trying to find an array named `@hostname` and expand it.  `@hostname` is not set, so it is expanding to `rsync -qtz user:/tmp/p /tmp`.

Try

```
system("rsync -qtz user\@hostname:/tmp/p /tmp");
```

instead.